# Logging in with a secondary encrypted luks drive

Tags: debian, luks

I added another drive in my Debian machine and also encrypted it using Luks.  So using the following instruction from this [site](https://www.erianna.com/adding-an-secondary-encrypted-drive-with-lvm-to-ubuntu-linux/), I got it to work.  My question, however is that I thought that in my setup, where I create a key file

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sd?X /root/.keyfile
```

I assumed that since I used the same password as my main encryption and mount the main drive, it would automatically unencrypt and mount the secondary drive.  But it's asking me to add my login to the new drive during boot

[image]

Am I just understanding it?  That you still need to enter your password since it's a different drive?  Or should it also unencrypt the secondary drive?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, but Linux does not remember your password. You may not need tje password to mpunt the disk because there is a key file, but as this appears to be being mounted automatically you need to specify the key to the mounting process (maybe in crypttab)

Comment: I redid it again and I think I messed up with the keyfile.  The second time it worked without any issue